# non-wasteful way to store subgraphs

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory

Suppose I have 6 elements: A, B, C, D, E, and F.  A connects to B (alternatively B connects to A -- there's no notion of direction), B connects to C, D connects to E, and F is not connected to anything.  But what I actually want is not the direct connections but just to know which elements have some path connecting them.

I know one way of encoding this in Python is with a 6x6 adjacency matrix.  But as it's a fairly sparse matrix, that is memory wasteful.

The other way I know of with a dictionary.  Here's how it would look in Python.

```
graph = {
    A: [B, C],
    B: [A, C],
    C: [A, B],
    D: [E],
    E: [D],
    F: []
}
```

However, this structure really seems to be better at keeping track of direct connections rather than connected subgraphs.  In particular, there is a lot of wasted memory being used as for example `A: [B, C]` and `B: [A, C]` encode the exact same thing.

Can anyone recommend a data structure that would be better for storing this information and/ or an algorithm for creating that structure which scales better than either an adjacency matrix or the above dictionary?

Comment: How about a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure ?

Comment: I'm looking into it now.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: When you say there is no notion of connection I assume you are dealing with an undirected graph. An undirected graph can be represented by the adjacency list by the way you have represented above. Matrix representation could be sparse and is inefficient for sparse nodes. Disjoint set can be a better alternative if you are looking for memory efficiency but you might loose edge information when you convert it to DJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Disjoint Sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). Here is possible implementation:

```
# Implementation of Union-Find (Disjoint Set)
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.values = [value]
        self.parent = self
        self.rank = 0

    def find(self):
        if self.parent.parent != self.parent:
            self.parent = self.parent.find()
        return self.parent

    def union(self, other):
        node = self.find()
        other = other.find()
        if node == other:
            return True # was already in same set
        if node.rank > other.rank:
            node, other = other, node
        node.parent = other
        other.rank = max(other.rank, node.rank + 1)
        other.values.extend(node.values)
        node.values = None # Discard
        return False # was not in same set, but now is

nodes = "ABCDEF"
edges = ["AB", "AC", "DE"]

# create Node instances
nodes = {node: Node(node) for node in nodes}
# process the edges
for a, b in edges:
    nodes[a].union(nodes[b])

# now do a query
print("group with 'B' {}".format(nodes["B"].find().values))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some libraries in Python such as `networkx` or `igraph`

**Networkx**

I was using `networkx` for a long time. It's [documented](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/) very well. I'll show here what's the difference between directed and undirected graphs:

**Directed:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
A, B, C, D, E, F = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'
dictionary = {A: [B, C], B: [A, C], C: [A, B], D: [E], E: [D], F: []}
G = nx.DiGraph(dictionary)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Connected components can be accessed like so:

```
>>> print([list(n) for n in nx.strongly_connected_components(G)])
[['B', 'A', 'C'], ['D', 'E'], ['F']]
```

**Undirected:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
A, B, C, D, E, F = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'
dictionary = {A: [B], B: [C], C: [A], D: [E], F: []}
G = nx.Graph(dictionary)
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Connected components can be accessed like so:

```
>>> print([list(n) for n in nx.connected_components(G)])
[['B', 'A', 'C'], ['E', 'D'], ['F']]
```

Comment: This shows how to compute them, but the question is how to store them.

Comment: I use, at least, twice reduced dictionary of graph:
`dictionary = {A: [B], B: [C], C: [A], D: [E], F: []}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can express your relationships as sets of characters and compute the sets of connected characters using the Python solution to the Rosetta Code task "Set consolidation" [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Set_consolidation#Python:_Iterative).

```
>>> consolidate([set('AB'), set('BC'), set('DE'), set('F')])
[{'A', 'C', 'B'}, {'E', 'D'}, {'F'}]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets for this.

```
Set1: {A, B, C},
Set2: {D, E},
Set3: {F}
```

If you need to quickly go from an element to its set, use a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If you're strictly looking for efficient storage of a non-directed graph, you could use a string with a couple of conventions.  First the node names pairings (edges) are always expressed in descending alphabetical (or alphanumerical) order. Second, you don't repeat the left side of that pairing by only listing related nodes after their larger counterpart.

This would give a string like this: "B,A|C,A,B|E,D|F"

You can go back and forth between this string encoding and the fully expanded dictionary representation in memory (which will be necessary for any meaningful manipulation):

From string to dictionary:

```
sGraph = "B,A|C,A,B|E,D|F"
dGraph = { v:[] for v in sGraph.replace("|",",").split(",") }
dGraph.update({ v[0]:v[1:] for vG in sGraph.split("|") for v in[vG.split(",")]})
for v1,v2 in [(v1,v2) for v1,vN in dGraph.items() for v2 in vN]:dGraph[v2].append(v1)
```

Output:

```
print(dGraph) 
# {'B': ['A', 'C'], 'A': ['B', 'C'], 'C': ['A', 'B'], 'E': ['D'], 'D': ['E'], 'F': []}
```

note: depending on your processing needs the last for loop (above) could be omitted. This would give you a full representation of the graph with no redundancy in edges (but it would make it much harder to manipulate)

```
# {'B': ['A'], 'A': [], 'C': ['A', 'B'], 'E': ['D'], 'D': [], 'F': []}
```

Form dictionary to string (based on the fully expanded representation) :

```
dGraph = {'B': ['A', 'C'], 'A': ['B', 'C'], 'C': ['A', 'B'], 'E': ['D'], 'D': ['E'], 'F': []}
sGraph = sorted(v for v,vN in dGraph.items() if any(v2<v for v2 in vN) or not vN)
sGraph = "|".join( ",".join([v1,*(v2 for v2 in dGraph[v1] if v2<v1)]) for v1 in sGraph)
```

output:

```
print(sGraph)
# B,A|C,A,B|E,D|F
```

The length of the string will always be smaller than 2*(E+V) where E is the number of edges and V is the number of vertices (assuming one letter/character per vertex name).